# Umlauts changed in dataweave output

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have special characters in my json response which are german umlauts (ä,ö,ü).

I have set the encoding to UTF-8 and this should work but the output from dataweave is `Ã¼ and Ã¤ and Ã¶` and it is a `com.mulesoft.weave.reader.ByteArraySeekableStream` datatype.The input is a `byte[]`.

How can I set my workflow up so the response shows the umlauts and not junk?

**Dataweave Input Payload:**

```
{
  "id": 1234567890
  "name": "prod123",
  "desc": "ü and ä and ö"
}
```

**Dataweave Mapping:**

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
{
    "status": 0,
    "desc": payload.desc
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "desc": "Ã¼ and Ã¤ and Ã¶"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are reading or logging your JSON response using UTF-8 encoding? Maybe its properly encoded, but as your output is a Byte stream, if you are somehow decoding using another encoding (such as ASCII) it may seem an error. Also, are you sure the input payload is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: I have set the content type of the message to application/json; charset=UTF-8.  I am also having problems with Chinese characters like 傳 too.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the encoding property on output from your dataweave script and you should get proper output as expected. I tested in my local and it works fine.
The reason it does not work with UTF-8 is because your input might be encoded with some other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to run on an older windows version?
There is a problem where mule does not honor the UTF-8 output directive.

Mule support:

> You might be running into a known issue that System property
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 is ignored in a windows environment. ..... You can try it using Mule 4.1.3 as it has the fix for the known issue and
>   let me know if you still had the same issue or not.

You can try to set this system property in your runtime's wrapper.conf file, it might fix your issue.